# How do I use my AngularJS and django web application for cordova based mobile application?

Tags: python, angularjs, django, cordova, jquery-mobile

I am new to django, I have AngularJS + django made web application. I have to work on for mobile application using cordova. How do I use my web application for cordova based mobile application ? How do I install django for cordova mobile application and use the same code ?

Thanks

Comment: Such questions are generally closed because of being _Too Broad_: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to attempt to clear up some misconceptions from the question:

Cordova allows you to wrap **Client-Side** applications for use on Mobile, but not **Server-Side** applications. Django is a server-side framework, so you will not be able to package it with Cordova.

Conceptually, imagine you have a simple message-board application with the following functionality:

1. Anybody can go to the website and type out a message.
2. That message is then posted on the main page for everyone to see.

For this to work, there has to be a server with a database that stores all the messages and serves them up whenever someone visits the site. So this is the Django part of the application, and it should be pretty clear that there has to be just **one** of these running.

If each person had their own copy of this part of the application, then you'd never be able to see messages posted by anyone else and nobody else would ever be able to see your messages. For this reason, Django applications (and any other "server-side" applications) can't be packaged with Cordova and sent out as a part of a mobile application. Instead, there's just one of them and it knows how to answer requests coming from multiple different "client-side" applications (like mobile apps).

Now lets imagine an Angular (or other javascript) application that is the "Client-Side" portion of this application. It runs in the browser, not on the server, and each user gets their own copy of it. These Angular applications all know how to ask the Django server for a list of messages (using the server-side application's API), and they know how to send a new message to the Django server (again, using the API). They also provide a nice, pretty user-interface for viewing and composing those messages. Now *this* is something that will work with Cordova because it's a "client-side" application.

There's no inherent difference between a client-side application that runs in the browser and connects to a server and a client-side application that runs on a mobile device and connects to a server. They just need to be written in different languages with different formats. Cordova makes it easier to "translate" a client-side application that runs in the browser to the language and format necessary for it to be a valid mobile app.

Specifically, if you were using Angular for the client-side portion of your application, you may want to take a look at [Ionic framework](http://ionicframework.com/). It's built specifically for translating Angular applications to mobile using Cordova.

I hope this helped clear a few things up and point you in the right direction.

Cheers